# Alias - command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, alias

I am trying create own aliases in terminal (Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1).

I added this lines:

```
alias apr='sudo apachectl restart'
alias setvhost='sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf'
alias setdns='sudo nano /etc/hosts'
```

to this files: (I know that lines should be only in one of the following files)

```
~/.profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashhrc
```

but after restart this aliases not working. After type `apr` i get `zsh: command not found: apr`

What I doing wrong? 
Which file is best for set aliases?

---

EDIT/ANSWER:

I am using `Oh My ZSH!` so my default shell is `ZSH` and setting of symlinks is currently in `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your default shell is zsh, not bash; zsh will not read .bashrc etc. at startup. Change your default shell to bash and retry.

Comment: Good point! Yes I have zsh but i want use this... So i symlinks set in `~/.zshrc` file and now it works :)